# Q_PROPERTY in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, properties

I cant really figure out why do I need it, Been reading:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/properties.html#requirements-for-declaring-properties

still cant really understand the use of it.
any kind of help would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read about the [Qt Property System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html) , this is just like a usual class method but it can be used with Qt's meta-object system:

```
 QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
 QObject *object = button;

 button->setDown(true);
 object->setProperty("down", true);
```

Also these properties will be visible under Qt Designer too so you could create a custom widget with some properties and hook it up in Qt Designer, see [this article](http://www.serenethinking.com/2010/08/how-to-integrate-custom-widgets-in-qt-designer/) for details.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that these properties are accessible from QtScript.

Comment: Also properties are accessible from CSS

Comment: The big one for me is using custom widgets as plugins in Designer.  The items declared as properties then show up to be set via designer.

Comment: The first link is dead. I can't understand the use of Q_PROPERTY still :(

Answer (score 0):

Properties help in RTTI like implementation using Qt's Meta object system.