# What is the classic scenarios of using Qt Property System

Tags: qt

It seems that Qt Property System is very powerful.

But I don't know when should I use it.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722279/q-property-in-qt) here, but it seems it doesn't answer my question.

Could  anyone give an example to show it power in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Qt property system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) is powerful when dealing with the runtime environment. You are able access the properties without knowing anything about the class in use through the QObject interface.

Also, if you implement your GUI using QML and your model using Qt C++ then model properties are [available](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties) for GUI through the property system. As an example, a property value in the model is changed and the change is triggered to the GUI through the property system.

Comment: This is right. Qt Designer is a standard-GUI-Tool, so one use-case is to have the Widget's properties editable in QtDesigner. (Like all other Widget properties).

Answer (score 1):

The existing accepted answer is good and correct, I would only like to add a couple of cases in which Qt properties are very useful.

One of the key points of QML is property bindings, which means that when a property's dependencies change in value, the property is automatically updated according to the specified relationship. This is true for properties defined in QML but also for properties defined in C++ through the Qt property system. If you expose a C++ object to QML, you can bind to its properties in QML and cause UI changes from C++ code with simple assignments. Also Qt 6 introduced a technique to use property binding directly in C++ through [QBindable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbindable.html).

In addition, Qt property system adds a way to enumerate properties and values runtime. This is very useful, for example I used this to automatically serialize and deserialize JSON strings and QObject's: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqobjectserializer, like gson does.

The concept of C++ properties and their excellent use in QML is so relevant to me that, in some cases, I need to create hundreds or thousands of properties to expose data to QML. Writing a Qt property with a stored C++ variable is very verbose, so I implemented some macros to create a stored property in one single line: https://github.com/carlonluca/lqtutils#synthetize-qt-properties-in-a-short-way-lqtutils_proph.

Note that links point to personal projects that are completely open source with permissive license.